# Python: How to unpack tuples in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm currently storing data into a dictionary as a tuple, but I don't know how to unpack the tuple from the dictionary itself.  I get a ValueError saying too many values to unpack in the way I am trying to do it.  Here is the code:

```
for row in csvReader:
    if row['de_description'] and row['nh_description']:
        if 'XT2R' in row['de_description']:
            id = (row['de_description'], row['nh_description']:
            if ('TCN' in row['de_description'] and '77880' in row['src_dp']:
                rounded_time = int(float(row['rr_polltime']))
                dataDict[id].append((rounded_time, row['rr_age']))
                timeSet.add(rounded_time)
    fileHandle.close()

    #unpacking tuple?
    for id, (valX,valY) in dataDict.iteritems():
        ageSet.add(valY)
    print "ageSet=", ageSet
```

I also realize there is a lot of redundancy in my code but that is not currently my issue.  If anyone has ever worked with unpacking tuples from a dictionary, pointing me in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Could you, for convenience, give us an example of a dataDict dictionary? Just add a print of dataDict after your for loop.

Comment: The csv I'm reading in his huge, but I can give you some of the last items.
(1412780306, '4493'), (1412780396, '4584')]})

Comment: Could you provide one row of csv file?

Answer (score 0):

Referring to

```
dataDict[id].append((rounded_time, row['rr_age']))
```

your `dataDict` seems to be a dictionary of lists, since you append values (tuples, in this case) to `dataDict[id]`.
`dataDict.iteritems()`, however, returns an `iter` object of *key-value-pairs*, which are the dictionary key and the list.

Trying to unpack the list into `(valX, valY)` results in the `ValueError` you experience.

Comment: How would I be able to unpack the tuple? I want to get the second item in the tuple.

Comment: what does your `dataDict` look like?

Comment: ({[(1412780306, '4493'), (1412780396, '4584')]}) but a lot more values (csv is about 1GB)

Comment: The problem you encounter seems to base on data types and data structure confusion. If you would take a few lines from your csv file, add (or link) them to your question, add your desired internal data structure (your `dataDict` as you would like it to be) and your desired output (`ageSet`), we would be much more able to help you.

Comment: @Kevin: In other words, provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us in your question, not a tiny snippet of code.